How to get messages of a group with chat_id and access_hash?
I have a Python script where I fetch messages of a channel using the following code:
entity = InputPeerChannel(int(chat_id), int(chat_hash))

async for message in client.iter_messages(entity, reverse = True, offset_date = offset_date):
#Some stuff to save messages

This works perfectly fine with channels, however I also have groups for which I get the ChannelInvalidError. Which function do I have to use to fetch messages for groups if I have their chat_id and access_hash?

Try entity = client.get_input_entity(...)

@inspectorG4dget Do I try it just with the group name? I remember client.get_input_entity(...) not taking access_hash as input

IIRC, that method works with a URL. It might also work with some other inputs. I'd recommend looking at the documentation and the sourcecode and then trying a few inputs
